# iPhone "page curl" icon is disappered in iOS 5

Tags: iphone

Does not SDK page curl icon anymore?
page curl icon is used on native map app (http://www.filemaker.com/products/bento/iphone/1/help/en/images/icon_page_curl.png)

I can assign page curl icon in iOS 5, but icon does not appear on tool bar. 
this icon is appear in under iOS 5. 
do you have any idea of this?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it yet?

Comment: Same thing here. The built-in curl icon was never great (for example if you tried a custom colour scheme the built-in curl button stayed blue unlike all the other buttons), but it disappearing altogether in IOS5 takes the cake!

Comment: yup i have the same issue. thanks for asking this.

Comment: I don't have any solution for this. and I found that guide line sugges page curl icon is used for page curl effects like map app. so I changed icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this person created their own page curl icon.  You can use this one (it's under an open license):

http://blog.shuningbian.net/2011/01/ios-toolbar-pagecurl-icon.html

I just took this, resized the image to 20x20 and plan used it in a custom UIBarButtonItem it in my app.  It doesn't look quite as nice as apple's, but it works!

Comment: Thanks. I don't knwo why ios 5 does not support native page curl icon,  I decide to use custom icon like yours

Comment: yea i found it surprising as well.  Nice thing about using a custom icon is that it will work in versions prior to iOS 4 as well.

Comment: Nice find. But as you say Apple's looks so much better and with the little piece sticking out of the button frame, it's impossible to recreate.

Comment: haha yeah apple's looks really good!  yeah that is a really good point.  plus it sucks because part of the nice thing about that icon is that it has the same look and feel as google maps, which is great if you are doing a mapping app like me.

Comment: I imagine it's possible if you created your own custom UIView and could design the necessary graphics, but you are right it's certainly not possible as a UIBarButtonItem with a custom image.  That would be a way better solution than mine.

Comment: I have to say doing the page curl effect in general has given me so much trouble (buttons and the modal effect itself) I wish I never started down that road.  I've never gotten it to work quite right.

Comment: Well well well. I can only say I am happy the goal of releasing that icon has been met :) I do apologise for the quality of the icon... just a programmer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I just got answer from Apple that the problem has been determined and is a known issue.

So we all can just hope they will fix this in iOS 5.1 release.

Comment: I can now confirm that the problem is fixed in iOS 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can give this tool a shot to try and extract the icon from UIKit on a version 4 device:

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor